# Inner Join 2 tables multiple result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have 2 tables, one for the products and one for the sizes.
they have a relation with fk and the problem is that when I'm using the inner join I cannot use the "group by" in order to don't have repeated results. 
this is the code:

```
SELECT
sneakers.sneaker_id,
sneakers.sneaker_name,
sneakers.gender,
sneakers.description,
sneakers.price,
sizes.size,
brand_names.brand_name
FROM sneakers
INNER JOIN sizes ON sneaker_fk = sneaker_id
```

if i try to use the `GROUP BY sneaker_fk` it will give me this response:

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT sneakers.sneaker_id,sneakers.sneaker_name, sneakers.gender, sneakers.description,
                                    sneakers.price, sizes.size, brand_names.brand_name FROM sneakers
                                    INNER JOIN sizes ON sneaker_fk = sneaker_id
                                    INNER JOIN brand_names ON brand_name_fk = brand_name_id
                                    GROUP BY sneaker_fk LIMIT 0, 30
MySQL said: Documentation

#1055 - Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sneakerstore.sizes.size' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

What am I doing wrong?? 
Do you have any better solution to display One item with all the related sizes without having multiple results?

I hope you can help me as fast as possible! 
thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want to PIVOT the query so that the sizes returned in multiple rows become multiple columns of a single row per shoe.

Comment: If you using mysql 5.7 or above you need to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`  `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` but ensure first, this will not break other queries.

Comment: Why GROUP BY? I see no aggregate functions.

Comment: Learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  Google it.  Also, I don't see why you need `GROUP BY` since you don't have any aggregation.  Again, Google `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL's [Group_Concat()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function

The MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group.

Excerpt from [Using GROUP_CONCAT with joined tables](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1683-mysql-for-each-group-retrieve-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-a-given-column)

GROUP_CONCAT works with joins as well.

Let's say we have a table courses:

```
  | id | name |
  +—-+—————+
  | 1 | Ruby 101 |
  +—-+—————+
  | 2 | TDD for Poets |
  +—-+—————+'
```

We also have a second table bookings:

```
  | id | course_id |
  +—-+———–+
  | 7 | 1 |
  +—-+———–+
  | 8 | 1 |
  +—-+———–+
  | 9 | 1 |
  +—-+———–+
  | 10 | 2 |
  +—-+———–+
  | 11 | 2 |
  +—-+———–+


SELECT courses.name, GROUP_CONCAT(bookings.id)
FROM bookings
INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id == bookings.course_id
GROUP BY bookings.course_id;
```

The result set looks like this:

```
| courses.name | GROUP_CONCAT(bookings.id) |
+—————+—————————+
| Ruby 101 | 7,8,9 |
+—————+—————————+
| TDD for Poets | 10,11 |
+—————+—————————+
```

Comment: how should I use it with a join table?

Comment: @CamCam That's what Google is for.  There are tons of example on the web.

Comment: Thank you so much @WorkSmarter! 
I solved my problem with 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizes.size ), ',', 10 )


:D
Thanks again!